# Checkbox Event for Hitting "Enter" - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, web

I'm trying to design this web interface to let users navigate and enter/modify fields using only their keyboard. My hangup is at a checkbox that needs to change it's value when the "Enter" key is pressed while the checkbox has focus. I can write the C# stuff, just need to find a way to make this happen in ASP.NET.

How can I make a change in the ASPX code to point this checkbox to a C# function when the ENTER button is pressed while the checkbox has focus?

Thanks in advance :)

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Checked="True" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Billable" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the `onkeydown` event handler of the CheckBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
    Checked="True" Text="Billable" AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" 
    onkeydown="processKeyDown(this, event);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function processKeyDown(chk, e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            // Find the actual check box in the CheckBox ASP.NET control
            var chkBox = chk.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            chkBox.click();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't show up in the autofill list, but I'll try that out, thanks.

Comment: I modified the code inside `processKeyDown`. It simulates a click on the check box instead of setting the `checked` property. This way, the postback will be triggered (since the CheckBox as `AutoPostBack="true"`).

Comment: I'm not sure what I liked more, the use of JAVASCRIPT or the this=!this (just from a preference perspective). Regardless, this most beautifully fixed my issue. Not only that, it tied in beautifully with the already implemented OnCheckedChanged so that the required changes would occur on postback. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! The first version did not trigger the postback when `Enter` was pressed. With the current one, you control that behavior with the `AutoPostBack` property.